# Straddle neutral strategy

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, greeks, delta-hedging

What does it mean to implement a delta-neutral strategy for straddle ?

A straddle consists in buying a call and a put simultaneously, at the same date, on same underlying, with same maturity and strike.

It is possible to gain from a move up or down of underlying price, when move compensates for the primes.

What about a gain in a straddle strategy from delta-neutral management ?